# How can I install just pdfTeX and pdfLaTeX without additional stuff on a mac?

Tags: pdftex, installing

I am trying to install just pdfLaTeX without the rest of the stuff that comes in packages such as MacTeX. All I want to be able to do is convert LaTeX source files into pdf's. I downloaded the pdfTeX package from http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/ and followed the directions to install it, but I couldn't  do it properly. Can I create pdf files out of LaTeX source files with just pdfLaTeX? Also how do I install it?

Comment: How would you know which packages a document need? Just having `pdftex` or `pdflatex` is mostly not enough. Though, have a look at the netinstaller for Linux (it also run on a Mac just make sure to run it via `sudo`. There you can choose schemes, which may be smaller than just having MacTeX.

Comment: So in short I should just install the MacTeX 3GB package anyway.. I just saw it had a bunch of stuff like LuaTeX and other things I don't even know the use of.. I am just gonna install the MacTeX package without the GUI stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @JosephWright Perhaps a short answer is in order.

Answer (score 10):

The binary (pdfTeX) alone is not enough to compile a LaTeX document: it alone is not even enough for a plain TeX document. TeX needs for example a format file, fonts, and a way to *find* these. If you want something smaller than MacTeX, [BasicTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) is probably the place to look. It is a 'minimised' version of the same system, so can be expanded as needed (say it turns out you need one or two more packages than BasicTeX supplies). Another alternative is [KerTeX](http://www.kergis.com/en/kertex.html), although this means a more restricted set of binaries (no pdfTeX as KerTeX's licensing approach means no GPL software).